# Unknown collection member

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, expression, visibility

In a SSRS report my chart is linked to a dataset. However in the expression it says "Report item not linked to a dataset."

I like to hide the chart when no data is available. But because I cannot see the dataset it won't work. Even when I mention the dataset in the expression:

=IIf(Count(Fields!hostname.Value, "DataSetName")=0,True,False)

It gives me this error when I hover over "hostname.Value" => "Unknown collection member."

I've already remove the .data file because it was suggested here, but that doesn't work.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the charts visibility property by writing an expression using [CountRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
= IIf (CountRows("dataset1") > 0, false, true)
 or 
= IIf (CountRows() > 0, false, true)
```

Or else go to the property window of the chart .You will see NoDataMessage expand it and in the caption mention

```
No data available
```

and set the property to false